# What is the gradient of this function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Imagine you have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$f(z):=z^TAz$, where $A$ is a symmetric matrix. Now I was wondering what
$\nabla f(x_1,...,x_{n-1},\gamma(x_1,...,x_{n-1}))$, where $\gamma$ is some differentiable function $\gamma:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Does nobody know? My problem is that I do not know how to consider this special function $\gamma$.

Comment: This answer could be improved considerably if you were to explain what you have tried to do already.

Comment: I am confused by the fact how to deal with this special funciton $\gamma$. In my opinion, it does not matter for the differentiation(as you see by the other comment written under your answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Start by trying to find $(\nabla \!\operatorname{f})(x,\gamma(x))$ and then $(\nabla \!\operatorname{f})(x,y,\gamma(x,y))$.

Apply the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions) to your function where $x_n = \gamma(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})$.

Comment: I do not see it. in my opinion it would be $\nabla f(z) = Az$ and therefore $\nabla f(x_1,...,x_{n-1},\gamma(x_1,...,x_{n-1})) = A(x_1,...,x_{n-1},\gamma(x_1,...,x_{n-1}))$